# Catch specific key with the mysqlexception

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, exception

So I catch a MySqlException because I know I try to enter a duplicate primary key. If I call the Message it says for example:

```
"Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So it knows what key is causing the trouble, is there a way I can get that key (in this case '2') from the exception? I tried debugging it but couldn't find where it stores the value.

Comment: if you're entering a duplicate primary key, can't you just grab the key from the object you just tried to add?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: If you are not able to determine where the primary key value (in this case '2') gets loaded, it sounds like giving us some code is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert into method`: If you are using a loop for inserting your each value then;

> You can find it by using a `try-catch` statement.

`insert from method`: If you are using an insert statement for inserting values from another table or view then;

> Add a Where-Clues to your `select` statement, to insert not-exist values.

Like this one:

```
WHERE Not (ID IN (SELECT ID FROM DestinationTable))
```

And for finding all duplicates use that Where-Clues without `Not`, And you have all of them.